# Cant call Global Functions in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am very new to ASP.NET and I have a few functions that are starting to appear in multiple times across my project. I decided to grip them up in a single class file in my App_code folder.

In the code below I can call the TxtStrRight and the TxtStrLeft but when I use the GetDatDiff I am receiving the error "Does not exists in the current context".

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong.

I am calling this method with

```
<%# GetDiffDate(Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("DateTimeLogged"))) %>
```

My GlobalUtilities class file in my App-code folder

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Generic utilities that can be accessed from any page
/// </summary>
public static class GlobalUtilities
{

    //Takes x characters from the right hand side. Use Looks like MyString.TxtStrRight(8)
    public static string TxtStrRight(this string value, int length)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return string.Empty;

        return value.Length <= length ? value : value.Substring(value.Length - length);
    }

    //Takes x characters from the left hand side. Use Looks like MyString.TxtStrLeft(40)
    public static string TxtStrLeft(this string value, int length)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return string.Empty;

        return value.Length <= length ? value : value.Substring(0, length) + "...";
    }

    //Get the difference between time and date of NOW and the database value.
    public static string GetDiffDate(DateTime dt)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = dt - DateTime.Now;
        if (Math.Abs(ts.TotalHours) < 24 && Math.Abs(ts.TotalHours) >= 1)
        {
            return string.Format("{0:0} hrs ago", Math.Abs(ts.TotalHours));
        }
        else if (Math.Abs(ts.TotalHours) < 1)
        {
            return string.Format("{0:0} mins ago", Math.Abs(ts.TotalMinutes));
        }
        else
        {
            return dt.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The error is probably caused by Eval("DateTimeLogged"). For testing purpose, try to enter some hard-coded Date instead and see if it works. Depends on the test outcomes, apply the corrective action. Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (add the class name):

```
<%# GlobalUtilities.GetDiffDate(Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("DateTimeLogged"))) %>
```